# Should I put a termination resistor?

Tags: pcb-design, termination

I am a beginner in electronics and am trying to design a PCB where a buffer (BUF634A) output will be connected to an AD8138 (Differential ADC driver). In the PCB's previous iteration, I used a separate daughter board that hosts the differential ADC driver and the ADC itself. Now, I want to merge the daughter board into the main PCB.

I noticed that the daughterboard uses a termination resistor in its design. However, through googling, one of the articles mentioned that you don't have to put a termination resistor if it is not the first or the last stage of the system. I also try to run my circuit design on LTSpice, and without the termination resistor, my design works just fine.

Note: The signal bandwidth starts from DC to 1 MHz.

So, in my case, should I put a termination resistor between the BUF634A's output and the AD8138's input?

Comment: It would be nice with _any_ links to what you're talking about here, what do you mean but "last stage"? It's probably featured in one of those articles you are reading but we are not...

Comment: Both components seem to be "overqualified" for *bandwidth … DC to 1 MHz*: what accuracy are you aiming for? Does a series termination at the driver side hurt?

Comment: Depends on the circuit how they are connected. If you look at it, the buffer will be the start of chain and the driver will be the end, and also the driver will be the start of second chain with ADC input the end of second chain.

Comment: @greybeard It would be easier for me to calculate the Rf and Rg for the AD8138 if I didn't have to use a termination resistor. I still don't understand how to choose the right termination resistor value if I use one. Regarding the accuracy, the AD8138 will be connected to a 12-bit ADC and the signal will be 1 V peak-to-peak.

Comment: @pipe Sorry for the confusion, here is the article that I mentioned: https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2019-termination-resistors-their-function-and-necessity-on-pcbs

Comment: (Do not comment comments asking for additional information (such as a hyperlink to an article mentioned) or clarification: `Edit` your post.)